# How to Show custom Emojis Url link in Labels iOS

Tags: ios, uilabel, stack-overflow, nsattributedstring, emoji

[image]How to show Emojis url link in label. Emojis Unicode format is showing properly but when we show emojis url link its not showing its show same URL link.

I am using this code for showing Emojis:-
 NSString *html = msCommentObj.mCommentText;

```
NSAttributedString *attr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                    options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                              NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                                         documentAttributes:nil
                                                                      error:nil];
NSString *finalString = [attr string];
descriptionCommentsLbl.text = finalString;*
```

Here is the Emojis Response :- 
     True.

https://mysponsers.com//img/emoticons/47.png https://mysponsers.com//img/emoticons/41.png

Comment: This might be interesting for you : - https://stackoverflow.com/q/19318421/4970453

Comment: `descriptionCommentsLbl.attributedText = attr` instead?

Comment: same URLs are not showing
https://mysponsers.com//img/emoticons/47.png https://mysponsers.com//img/emoticons/41.png

Comment: Could you show `html`?

Comment: Here is the my screenshot.

Comment: Yes i can but i need to show images and emojis

Comment: And `descriptionCommentsLbl.attributedText = attr` is not working? Because your were using it's `string` property, which doesn't have images.

Comment: Can you please help me how to use how to add images How to add images please

Comment: Show `html`, and `attr`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146242/discussion-between-mss-ios-and-larme).

Comment: Already Showing