# Is it possible to get image and text from UITextview? swift

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, uitextview

I want to make a note app like Apple native Notes app.

I've put an image in a UITextview. I used NSTextAttachment().

Now I want to save content (text and image) to a server.

I can get text by using `UITextView text` method.

But I can't get the image object.

There is no subclass `UITextview image`.

How can I get image at textview? Is it possible?

Comment: Look at `UITextView attributedText`.

Comment: @rmaddy  Thanks ...and... I want to get already added image from textview

Comment: Yes, the attributedText will include the attachment and the text.

Comment: Check the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152660/extract-uiimage-from-nsattributed-string/29153172#29153172

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you very much!! You are my hero~~~~~~~!!!!!!

Comment: @OnurTuna Thnk you very very much~~