# How to save image and text in UITextView in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller, userdefaults

I am adding both text and image in UITextView to part of my app ( similar to the notes app ). The user can write a text and/or then select a picture from the photo library or take a picture ( with image picker). 
I managed to add the text and the image into the UITextView. I **can save** the text but can’t figure out how to save the image. I have looked very similar questions but still having a hard time getting the code. I have tried to do it with userDefaults but apparently it’s not the right way. Maybe documents directory or file path but I don’t know how to do that. Any help will be much appreciate it.
This is the code I have:

```
class NotesViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
   var pickImage: UIImage!
   var attString = NSAttributedString()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textView.delegate = self
    self.isModalInPresentation = true
    textView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive  // .onDrag
    
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    
    textView.textColor = UIColor.self.init(red: 222/255, green: 215/255, blue: 191/255, alpha: 1.0)
    textView.font = UIFont(name: "Trebuchet MS", size: 19)
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textView.tintColor = UIColor.self.init(red: 141/255, green: 124/255, blue: 85/255, alpha: 1.0)
    
    textView.layer.masksToBounds = false


    if let value = userDefault.value(forKey: myNotes) as? String {

        textView.text = value

    }
    textView.alwaysBounceVertical = true


    }

 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

      pickImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage

      //create and NSTextAttachment and add your image to it.
      let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
      attachment.image = pickImage

      //calculate new size.  (-20 because I want to have a litle space on the right of picture)
      let newImageWidth = (textView.bounds.size.width - 15 )
      let scale = newImageWidth/pickImage.size.width
      let newImageHeight = pickImage.size.height * scale - 20

      //resize this
      attachment.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: newImageWidth, height: newImageHeight)

      //put your NSTextAttachment into and attributedString
      attString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)

      //add this attributed string to the current position.
      textView.textStorage.insert(attString, at: textView.selectedRange.location)
      textView.selectedRange.location += 1
      
      textView.textColor = UIColor.self.init(red: 222/255, green: 215/255, blue: 191/255, alpha: 1.0)
      textView.font = UIFont(name: "Trebuchet MS", size: 19)
      textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
      textView.tintColor = UIColor.self.init(red: 141/255, green: 124/255, blue: 85/255, alpha: 1.0)
      textView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive

      picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

 }

 func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
       picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

 @objc func saveText() {

    userDefault.setValue(textView.text, forKey: myNotes)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are one important you need to know:

- Everything you customize like add image, add icon, ... you always do on `NSAttributedString` not the plain text.

So at your func `saveText` you call:

```swift
userDefault.setValue(textView.text, forKey: myNotes)
```

Means that you store only the plain text from your `textView` which is `textView.text` but not storing all the special attributes combine in your `textView` which is `textView.attributedText`. That's the main reason you not getting the image with you when saving.

For do that, you need to make two function: One to store your attributed text to `UserDefault` and one to get from `UserDefault` to appear

For the first one, which is store your attributed text to `UserDefault`. We can not save directly `NSAttributedString` to `UserDefault` so we need to convert it to `Data` first and store it.

```swift
func saveAttributedTextToUserDefault(attributedText: NSAttributedString, key: String) {
    do {
        let data = try attributedText.data(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length), documentAttributes: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtfd])
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(data, forKeyPath: key)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The second one, simply get the data from `UserDefault` and convert it back to `NSAttributedString`

```swift
func getAttributedTextFromUserDefault(key: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    if let dataValue = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key) as? Data {
        do {
            let attributeText = try NSAttributedString(data: dataValue, documentAttributes: nil)
            return attributeText
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
        }

    }

    return NSAttributedString()
}
```

The usage

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // your others code
    let attributedText = self.getAttributedTextFromUserDefault(key: "test")
    textView.attributedText = attributedText
}

@objc func saveText() {
    // take attributedText and save it
    self.saveAttributedTextToUserDefault(attributedText: textView.attributedText, key: "test")

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Everything works great. I was able to save text and image(s) and retrieve them. The only problem that I am facing right now is that the image doesn't resize. When I pick it, looks fine in the textView but when I save it doesn't not keep the original scale down. How do I save that in the function? You can see in the my code above that I am using NSTextAttachment(). Thanks again in advance for your help!!!

Comment: Dear @Dian, the problem you say is out of scope of this question. You should make another question or try it yourself.  Hint is make a func to convert from the ``NSAttributedString`` from UserDefault and make new ``NSAttributedString`` with text and resize image. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152660/extract-uiimage-from-nsattributed-string/29153172#29153172

Comment: Dear @bewithyou. Thanks again for the tip and the hint. I have seen the link you sent. Still don't understand it. I have been trying and reading but I am a beginner and can not get it to work with my code.